# Why is tabindex=0 adding element to logical order

Tags: html, keyboard, moodle

I have been working on accessibility issues for a major project. Part of the work involved adding tabindex=0 to quite a lot of buttons and links as they were not being focused on when a user tabbed through the page.

I was building this all in my local environment where it was working fine. Basically once I added tabindex=0 to an element it would be tabbed to in the logical order. The logical order being its position in the page source. So the first elements in the page source were tabbed to first going down to the last elements (as you would expect.)

I have pushed this code up to a testing site. While testing on this site I experienced something quite different. When I first navigate to a page and start pressing tab:

1. It tabs through all the tabindex=0 items in logical order
2. It then tabs through all the other elements in logical order.

The issue is I don't have time to add tabindex=0 to every element. I thought the entire point of it was just to add it to elements that were were not being focused on. Now that some elements have tabindex=0 and some don't it creates this jumpy effect where it loops through the page twice, first time getting tabindex=0 and second time getting all the other elements. This is not ideal and will not pass QA.

Any ideas and what could have caused this change? I tested both sites using Chrome. The only difference is one is being run in MAMP (my local environment) and one is a server hosted on AWS? I don't see how server infrastructure should effect html behaviour though.

## Edited

I can't show any of the HTML page due to IP. I was fishing for more of a theoretical answer as to why this would happen and as to the behaviour of tabindex=0 in different environments.

Update: So I took a look at the test site vs my local site and apparently on the test site it is injecting tabindex='112' into all elements it suspects should be in tab focus. So it is now looping through all my tabindex=0 then looping through all the generated tabindex='112'. This is a Moodle site so not sure what is causing the injection.

Comment: Usually you don't use tab index=0 unless the element is not naturally indexed. The files being served differently will not affect the indexes since they are simply being served. It should be up to the browser to decide what order to tab. Are you using any sort of templating engine?

Comment: Thank you Keegan! Not sure if this was what you meant by templating engine but take a look at my edited question.

Comment: Other devs though I chatted to them and none of them did it. We are building our product on top of Moodle, an over source software. It must be Moodle that is causing this injection. Is it to risky to change all my tabindex=0 to tabindex=112 so that they will be part of the tabbing order? Anyway to know if this will change down the track?

Comment: So Moodle could be the culprit.

Comment: You could leave all elements without a tabindex and let the browser find the best path.

Comment: Is it the whole site that is affected or just the one page?

Comment: No the whole reason I had to fix it was that the browser was not identifying key links and buttons as part of the list so I have to manually do it. Whole site but in particular the menu bars which come from the same code throughout the site.

Comment: Try setting the indexes to -1. The browser should then automatically set the correct index value.